# extjs4 - merge store into another

Tags: extjs, extjs4

I have a data view that renders a store of data.

Once in a while the user may opt in to add more items through different sources.

When that happens, i create a new store and loop through the result and add them to the primary data view store.

Is there a better way to merge two stores? or append loaded data to a store rather than refreshing it entirely?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out the `loadRecords` method of Ext.data.Store

> Loads an array of model instances into the store, fires the
>   datachanged event. This should only usually be called internally when
>   loading from the Proxy, when adding records manually use add instead
>
> Parameters
>
> records : Ext.data.Model[] The array of records to load
>
> options : Object {addRecords: true} to add these records to the
>   existing records, false to remove the Store's existing records first

Comment: Cool. Do you know if I can pass the 2nd store's data property directly to the loadRecords function of the first one? data is a MixedCollection by loadRecords expects and Array.

Comment: I guess i could just use getRange() on the collection to turn it into an array.

Comment: Yeah it looks like getRange is exactly what you need.